# Why do PPAs get errors after an upgrade?

Tags: installation, upgrade, ppa

I have a question??
After Upgrading to a newer  version of ubuntu every time for some time I have problems with getting software from launchpad.

So I have a question why does that happens why does ubuntu can not use a file that previous version of ubuntu could, and why does not every dev adds support from the day one ??
Is it a lot of work to make it run on a new ubuntu ???

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Each release of Ubuntu is a complicated "stack" of software and libraries.
- Applications are very often built against specific versions of these libraries (eg various Python libraries or libc versions) and therefore a PPA needs to be built for a release of Ubuntu.
- Updating the stack can introduce new bugs that weren't there in the older builds.
- Any package developer with half a conscience will want to build and test the software locally before pushing it up to Launchpad for public consumption.

That all takes time and as you might note PPA stands for ***Personal*** Package Archive. These are mostly from volunteers who have donated their time to package stuff up for themselves and other users.

More than that, testing the software also requires that the developer has also upgraded their local install. I need my computer for my job. I don't upgrade for at least I wait at least a month before I upgrade. I would imagine there are other developer who wait longer.

If you need a precise reason for something, talk to the person in charge of a PPA. It's usually just one person who only issues new builds when there's a new upstream. In the case of Handbrake:

> For questions and bugs with software in this PPA please contact [John Stebbins](https://launchpad.net/~stebbins).

Just remember that they're a person and not a company you've paid money to.

Comment: I know that.
What I want to know is why does not every dev supports the never version of ubuntu from the first day do they need to do a lot of work on their software to make it run on a never version of ubuntu or they are just lazy ??

Comment: They're not lazy, it's volunteer work. Making an OS is hard work.

Comment: Lazy? Most PPAs aren't run by Canonical employees. They're not being paid. In most cases I would guess they might have something better to do. Like their `$DAYJOB`.

Comment: Why can not I delete this question it is wrong in so many ways.
Well for example why did not handbrake add support of 13.10 after the first day of the release. so what I want to know is how hard is it to make it run on the new version. Is it hard and that is why we do not get support of the new version?? or there is a different reason

Comment: Don't confuse difficulty with time. Handbrake *might* build fine and require no significant change in packaging, but it still takes a real person's time to issue that build. If you want to employ somebody to compile stuff for you, you'll get same-day builds of all the software... Until then, you'll have to wait or do the work yourself like the rest of us.

Comment: Yes, it can be very hard. Software is often written expecting other Linux packages to work in a specific way, and when they change, that can break your package. As to why, perhaps contacting the PPA maiintainer https://launchpad.net/~stebbins might result in some answers.

Comment: @Levan if the question is wrong just hit the edit button and improve it.

Comment: y-ppa-manager is a great package to speed adding/removing PPAs. You don't need to update apt after adding a PPA this way: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager

Comment: @Alvar
well it is completely off this is a question I wanted to ask
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2185194
how ever because people show interest in this question or answare I will not be changing it and ignore it :(

Comment: @levan well ask a new question then.

Comment: I think this answer (as edited) answers everything you've asked on Ubuntu Forums.

Comment: @alvar they answered my question on ubuntu forums. Thanks every one for the help